# Python SQLite3, table not showing updates

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a database with SQLite3 in Python.

Creating a table appears to work, but whenever I try to insert data, it doesn't seem to add anything to the database as fetchall() returns nothing, However, if I try to create the ID again, it complains about
unique constraint failed.

**Initialization:**

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('login.db')
c = conn.cursor()
```

**Table Creation:**

```py
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Login (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
First TEXT NOT NULL,
Last TEXT NOT NULL,
Middle TEXT NOT NULL,
Gender TEXT NOT NULL);""")
conn.commit()
```

**Data Insert:**

```py
c.execute("""INSERT INTO Login VALUES (6, 'First', 'Last', 'Hello', 'Male');""")
conn.commit()
```

**Fetching Tables:**

```py
print(c.fetchall())

c.close()
conn.close()
```

When dropping the table into an online reader, it also appears empty.

EDIT:
This is what is shown in the db reader, and in google sheets,
large list of blanks / ";" then this
[image]

Comment: Try to specify columns in your *INSERT* statement.

Comment: I did, it did nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c.fetchall()` would return all of the rows from a `SELECT` query, which you aren't doing.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('login.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Login (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, First TEXT NOT NULL, Last TEXT NOT NULL, Middle TEXT NOT NULL, Gender TEXT NOT NULL);""")
conn.commit()
c.execute("""INSERT INTO Login VALUES (6, 'First', 'Last', 'Hello', 'Male');""")
conn.commit()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM login")
print(c.fetchall())
```

will happily print

```
[(6, 'First', 'Last', 'Hello', 'Male')]
```

As an aside, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and you should do

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("login.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(
    """CREATE TABLE Login (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, First TEXT NOT NULL, Last TEXT NOT NULL, Middle TEXT NOT NULL, Gender TEXT NOT NULL);"""
)
conn.commit()
c.execute(
    "INSERT INTO Login (ID, First, Last, Middle, Gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
    (6, "First", "Last", "Hello", "Male"),
)
conn.commit()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM login")
print(c.fetchall())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: A few hours later I know but I looked into the SQL injection vulnerability part and it does seem like a big problem! This isn't production code but I didn't know about this vulnerability, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Even so, you would have bumped into the issue the first time you attempted to insert anything with quote characters :)